# What fire tests are done on power adapters/chargers?

Tags: power-supply, safety, adapter, ac-dc, ul

I was curious about the fire risks in using a typical AC-to-DC wall adapter
(e.g., [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084VVRDN7))
and went to the [UL website](https://www.ul.com/services/testing/safety-testing)
to learn what exact tests were done to get the "UL LISTED" stamp,
but I got lost and failed to find any details.
I honestly feel like UL wants me to get lost.

So, I googled instead and found [some UL Standards](https://www.compliancegate.com/ac-adapter-regulations-united-states/)
which I could purchase for hundreds of dollars each, but I don't even know which number
is relevant.  Again, it's obvious that UL wants to keep the details a secret (naturally,
they work to write these standards and want to get paid for it).  Would
it be illegal for someone to paraphrase the details here in an answer to me?  My instinct
is that a literal copy-and-paste would violate some copyright, but that there is no
copyright on the procedure itself...but I digress.

My real question: What exact tests are done by UL to confirm that the fire risk is low?

For example, I imagine that UL might crumple paper (something flammable) around
the adapter, plug it in, short the output for 30 minutes, and then confirm that
the paper is not burnt (and that the circuit breaker to wall power never tripped).
This test needs to be repeated for, say, 5 sample adapters to get the
"UL LISTED" stamp.  Is the actual UL testing anything like this?

Comment: I'd say quoting standards is problematic for reasoms they want money from you to purchase it. And it is unlikely that the test is as you describe, because it does not prove it  does not burn like a torch, only that it did not ignite yet. They likely try to make it burn and see if the flames go out or will it burn like a torch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to get a general idea, figure out what UL standards apply (you'll need the exact number) and put it in a search engine (not necessarily Google) and you'll likely find something (it might not be the current version, but it should be close).

Generally there will be some prescriptive stuff about using specific rated materials (eg. 94 V-1), analysis (which requires engineering knowledge) and testing (often to destruction) on a prescribed number of samples. For example, the pins should not be too easy to pull out because that could lead to a shock hazard.

If you're going to be **manufacturing** adapters or even buying large quantities you should purchase the current standard or access it from a library which carries them.

Comment: I found UL 1310, Apr 4 2000 revision, and Section 38 "Abnormal Tests" seems relevant. Though this section sometimes uses a cheesecloth to detect charring (analogous to the paper I mentioned), it does not apply cheesecloth for the output short-circuit test.  Also, 38.6 confuses me by suggesting that repeat tests are done for every possible component being damaged, but that would require a lot of units, so I am doubting my interpretation.  Could you add this level of detail to give the test that UL does which is closest to the test that I suggested in my question?

Comment: I believe the component breakdown testing is to be done with engineering knowledge applied, and as deemed necessary. There's no need to destroy a unit to simulate a shorted diode or whatever, you can simply short it if is deemed to be of interest.

Comment: Ok, that clears up my confusion about 38.6.  I am not interested as much in "engineering knowledge applied" to conclude that the adapter is good.  I am more interested in hands-on lab tests to conclude that the adapter is good (at preventing fires),  Can anyone add details about fire?